# ASP.NET Deserialize JSON with LINQ and loop through results

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, linq, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON string and then loop through it's results. 
I started here: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonLinq.htm

I want to translate that to a VB.NET version, but I'm getting all sorts of errors. 
I tried several translators without luck (such as http://converter.telerik.com/).

**JSON string**

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 1,
        "params": {
            "sort": "title asc"
            "rows": "10"
        }
    },
    "response": {
        "numFound": 3,
        "start": 0,
        "docs": [{
            "title": "Amsterdam",
            "cityurl": "amsterdam"
        }, {
            "title": "London",
            "cityurl": "london"
        }, {
            "title": "New York",
            "cityurl": "new-york"
        }]
    }
}
```

First I'm trying to deserialize the JSON:

```
Dim postTitles = From p In rss("channel")("item")DirectCast(p("title"), String)
'End of Statement Expected on `DirectCast(p("title"), String)`
```

Then I try to loop through the results, but both ways I've tried below don't work

```
For Each item As var In postTitles
    Log("title", item)
Next
'type 'var' is not defined

For Each (dim item In postTitles)
    Log("title", item)
Next
'Expression expected (on `dim`)
```

What is the correct code in VB.NET to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim data As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)

Dim postTitles = From doc In data("response")("docs")
                 Select doc("title").Tostring()

For Each item In postTitles
    Log("title", item)
Next
```

Reference: [Introduction to LINQ in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763068.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! With your code I get the design time error `Value of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' cannot be converted to 'String'.` on part `doc("title")`. I had to change that to `doc("title").ToString`, does that matter? It does generate the correct output now :)

Comment: @Flo, if this solves the issue related to your question, you can mark it as the answer. Thanks.